# Finite coproduct of finitely presentated objects is finitely presentated.

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Consider we are in an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$  then I define an object "M" in $\mathcal{C}$ as finitely presentated if there is an exact sequence $P_{1} \to P_{1} \to M \to 0$ such $P_{0}$ and $P_{1}$ are projective finetely generated objects in $\mathcal{C}$, where by and finitely generated object $P_{0}$ for example I mean that for every epimorhism

$$\oplus_{i \in I}Hom_{C}(-,C_{i}) \to P_{0} \to 0 $$ there is always  a finite set $J \subset I$
 such

$$\oplus_{i \in J}Hom_{C}(-,C_{i}) \to P_{0} \to 0 $$ is also an epimorhism.

So I want to prove thath if $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are finitely presentated objects then $M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ is finitely presentated where $M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ is the coproduct of $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ by thath i mean I have a family of morphism $\lbrace i_{i}:M_{i}  \to M_{1} \oplus M_{2} \rbrace_{i=1,2}$ which satisfy the universal property of the coproduct .

So Im really stucked trying to construct an exact sequence $P_{1}'' \to P_{0}'' \to M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ such $P_{1}'$ and $P_{0}''$ are projective finitely generated objects,  can anyone help me out by sketching me a glimpse of the proof or just guide me a little bit?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a projective finitely generated object in an abelian category?

Comment: I already give my definition of finitely generated object   by editing  the original question. :) @Qiaochu_Yuan

Comment: Got the answer by myself, hope to post it tomorrow! :D

Comment: If you have short exact sequences $P_1\to P_0\to M_1\to 0$ and $Q_1\to Q_0\to M_2\to 0$, why don't you take their (co)product $P_1\oplus Q_1\to P_0\oplus Q_0\to M_1\oplus M_2\to 0$?

Comment: (I mean "exact sequences", not "short", sorry.)